# Clojure: function arguments/signatures using macro or def

Tags: function, clojure, arguments, definition, reduce

I have many functions of the same long signature (shortened here for simplicity):

```
(defn f 
      [x & {:keys [a b c d e f g h]
            :or [a false b false c false d false e false f false g false h false]}]
      a)
```

I was hoping to use a macro, function, or even a def to store this common signature beforehand:

```
(def args `[a b c d e f g h])

(defn args [] `[a b c d e f g h])

(defmacro args [] `[a b c d e f g h])
```

but all of them, when I plugged into

```
(defn f 
      [x & {:keys (args)
            :or [a false b false c false d false e false f false g false h false]}]
      a)
```

ended up with errors like

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

So my two questions are:

1. Is there any way to define and use such a common `args`?
2. If such an `args` can be defined, I would also like to reduce it in order to get the `:or` params: `[a false b false c false d false e false f false g false h false]`.  How would this be done?  (I'm asking in case a working definition of `args` might be weird enough that this is no longer straightforward.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the stuff inside the argument vector in a `defn` doesn't get evaluated. However, you can define your own version of `defn`, like so:

```
user=> (defmacro mydefn [name & body] `(defn ~name ~'[a b c] ~@body))
#'user/mydefn
user=> (mydefn f (+ a b))
#'user/f
user=> (f 1 2 4)
3
```

Note the need for `~'` for the arguments. Otherwise syntax-quote (`` ` ``) would qualify the symbols into `user.a` etc.